# How to show if $H,K$ are normal subgroups in a group $G$ then $[H,K] \leq H \cap K$

Tags: group-theory

How to show if $H,K$ are normal subgroups in a group $G$ then $[H,K] \leq H \cap K$.

Here $[H,K]$ is the commutator subgroup.

I have tried to start it but instantly failed:

I want to show firstly that $[H,K]\subseteq H \cap K$ but I don't understand what an arbitrary element of $[H,K]$ would even look like so I have something to work on.

I thought it could look something like $h^{-1}k^{-1}hk$ but then I thought that we are working with the smallest subgroup containing elements of this form but that might not be what the actual elements are?

Could anyone help?

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $h^{-1}k^{-1}hk \in H \cap K$ for all $h \in H$, $k \in K$. If the generators of a subgroup all lie in $H \cap K$ then so does the subgroup itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that:
$$[H,K] = \langle [h,k] = hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\ |\ h\in H,\ k\in K\rangle.$$
It suffices to show that the generators of $[H,K]$are contained in $H$ and $K$. From the above, a typical generator of $[H,K]$ looks like $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$. Since $K$ is normal, you have $hkh^{-1} = k'$ for some $k'\in K$. Hence, 
$$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = k'k^{-1}\in K.$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay so we apply the same argument to get $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=hh' \in H$ in particular it is in both $H$ and $K$ so it would be in $H \cap K$?

Comment: @RyanS This follows from the fact that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups. By the above, if $a,b\in [H,K]$, then $a,b\in H$ and $a,b\in K$. Hence, $ab\in H$ and $ab\in K$. Therefore $ab\in H\cap K$. Since any product of generators of $[H,K]$ is in $H\cap K$, all of $[H,K]$ must lie in $H\cap K$.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now!

Comment: @RyanS Happy to help!

Comment: Can I ask one last question now we have shown it is a subset is it automatically a subgroup of $H \cap K$ since $[H,K]$ is a subgroup of $G$ by definiton?

Comment: @RyanS That's absolutely right.