# Suppose $G$ is a group and $H,K \trianglelefteq G$. If $H \cap K =1$ the $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K, h \in H$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H,K \trianglelefteq G$. If $H \cap K =1$ the $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K, h \in H$?

Here is what I have so far:

Take $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ we wish to show $hk=kh$ or equivalently $hkh^{-1}=k$. Now I know $hkh^{-1} \in K$ since $K$ is normal in $G$ but I don't know how to show that $hkh^{-1}=k$ i.e. it is the element we want it to be not some other element of $K$. I haven't used the fact that $H \cap K=1$ yet so I guess it follows as a consequence of that but I'm not seeing how at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch Proof:

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179713/how-to-show-if-h-k-are-normal-subgroups-in-a-group-g-then-h-k-leq-h-cap) that $[H,K]\le H\cap K$. In particular $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K$.

Comment: I got it now I think: $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in H \cap K$ so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=1$ then premultiply on the right first by $k$ then by $h$ yields $hk=kh$ for arbitrary $k \in K$ and $h \in H$. As we want. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It suffices to show that $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=1$.  Using the fact that $H$ and $K$ are both normal, what can you say about $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$?

Comment: It belongs to $H \cap K$ thus we must have it is equal to $1$ and we are done.